# Python idiom for for error checking in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a loop which looks like this:

```
errors += 1
for ...:
    ...
    if ...:
        logger.error(...)
        errors += 1
        continue
    ...
    if ...:
        logger.error(...)
        errors += 1
        continue
    ...
    if ...:
        logger.error(...)
        errors += 1
        continue
    ...
logger.info("%d errors",errors)
```

I wonder what the pythonic way to make it more readable is.

I can do

```
def e (fmt, *args):
    logger.error(fmt, *args)
    errors += 1
for ...:
    ...
    if ...:
        e(...)
        continue
    ...
    if ...:
        e(...)
        continue
    ...
    if ...:
        e(...)
        continue
    ...
logger.info("%d errors",errors)
```

or even

```
def e (cond, fmt, *args):
    if cond:
        logger.error(fmt, *args)
        errors += 1
    return cond
for ...:
    ...
    if e(...):
        continue
    ...
    if e(...):
        continue
    ...
    if e(...)
        continue
    ...
logger.info("%d errors",errors)
```

however, it doesn't look like I can do any better (no way to `continue`
from inside `e`).

Right?

(I think I can raise `StopIteration` in `e` to abort the iteration, but not something like a non-existent `ContinueIteration`).

Comment: Right off the bat, using `elif` in place of separate `if` statements that each use `continue` would be an improvement. However, this question (properly fleshed out) would probably be more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @chepner: this would result in a huge cascade of indentation. note the ellipses between the `if` clauses. there is a lot that is going on there.

Comment: I did miss those; I stand by my suggestion to reformulate the question for codereview, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feels to me like using exception handling is semantically appropriate and similarly concise as a function without the need for any `continue`:

```
for ...:
    try:
        # ...
        if ...:
            raise SomeException(...)
        # ...
        if ...:
            raise SomeException(...)
        # ...
        if ...:
            raise SomeException(...)
        # ...
    except SomeException as e:
        logger.error(e.message)
        errors += 1
```

Comment: Lovely! The only thing I don't like is the extra level of indentation for the body

Comment: True, one level deeper, but it avoids other readability issues like nested functions or `continue` statements while putting error handling where it belongs: in an `except` block.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a wrapper for the `logger` that record how many times `error` is called:

```
class CountingLogger:
    def __init__(self, real_logger, initial_errors=0):
        self.logger = real_logger
        self.errors = initial_errors
    def error(self, *args, **kw):
        self.logger.error(*args, **kw)
        self.errors += 1
```

Then you'd use something like `e = CountingLogger(logger)` and call `e.error()` inside the loop and afterwards you can access `e.errors` to see how many times it was called.  (naming could be better, `error` the method and `errors` the property are a bit too close for comfort)